# how to avoid dart2js discarding my angulardart callback

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart2js

I have a function that I think is being discarded by dart2js because it's only used in a AngularDart NgCallback, like this:

```
<my-component myCallback="myController.onLineupPositionClick()">
</my-component>
```

So, myCallback is exposed from my-component like this:

```
@NgCallback('myCallback')
Function myCallback;
```

And inside myController, the method is just a regular method:

```
void onLineupPositionClick() {
  print("HELLO");
}
```

The code works in the Chromium VM but not after compiling with "pub build" in Chrome or Firefox. The exception message is:

```
"No getter for 'onLineupPositionClick'.
```

I've verified that if I use the method inside a ng-click, it works:

```
<my-component ng-click="myController.onLineupPositionClick()" myCallback="myController.onLineupPositionClick()">
</my-component>
```

My bet is that dart2js is discarding the method because it can't see that angular will use it in the future.  ng-click somehow does something that precludes dart2js from discarding the method... but NgCallback doesn't do it, I don't understand why.

Am I right? What's the best solution?

Edited:
This is the exception I get:

```
"No getter for 'onLineupPositionClick'.

STACKTRACE:
.wrapException<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:3036:5
.StaticClosureMap.lookupGetter$1<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:11413:9
.StaticClosureMap.lookupFunction$2<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:11427:7
.DynamicParserBackend.newCallMember$3<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:9629:7
.DynamicParserImpl.parseAccessOrCallMember$0<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:9898:13
.DynamicParserImpl.parsePrefix$0<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:9887:9
.DynamicParserImpl.parseMultiplicative$0<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:9838:7
.DynamicParserImpl.parseAdditive$0<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:9819:7
.DynamicParserImpl.parseRelational$0<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:9788:7
.DynamicParserImpl.parseEquality$0<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:9769:7
.DynamicParserImpl.parseLogicalAnd$0<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:9757:7
.DynamicParserImpl.parseLogicalOr$0<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:9745:7
.DynamicParserImpl.parseConditional$0<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:9729:7
.DynamicParserImpl.parseExpression$0<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:9705:7
.DynamicParserImpl.parseFormatter$0<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:9690:7
.DynamicParserImpl.parseChain$0<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:9677:9
.DynamicParser_call_closure.call$0<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:9472:7
._LinkedHashMap.putIfAbsent$2<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:26121:7
.DynamicParser.call$1<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:9457:7
.ElementBinder._dom_internal$_parser$1@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:5995:7
.ElementBinder__createAttrMappings_closure.call$1<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:6245:11
.IterableMixinWorkaround_forEach<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:20146:7
.ElementBinder._createAttrMappings$6<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:6033:7
.ElementBinder__link_closure.call$1<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:6319:9
.IterableMixinWorkaround_forEach<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:20146:7
.ElementBinder._link$5<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:6043:7
.ElementBinder.bind$3<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:6121:7
.TaggingViewFactory._bindTagged$6<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:8523:7
.TaggingViewFactory._link$3<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:8554:13
.TaggingViewFactory.call$2<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:8500:9
.TaggingViewFactory.call$2<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:8508:7
.TranscludingComponentFactory_call__closure.call$1<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:8742:7
._rootRunUnary<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:21821:7
._ZoneDelegate.runUnary$3<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:24846:7
.VmTurnZone__onRunUnary_closure.call$0<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:13348:7
.VmTurnZone._onRunBase$4<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:13241:9
.VmTurnZone._onRunUnary$5<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:13261:7
anonymous/<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js line 3346 > Function:1:28
._ZoneDelegate.runUnary$3<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:24846:7
._CustomizedZone.runUnary$2<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:25061:7
._Future__propagateToListeners_handleValueCallback.call$0<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:22844:9
._Future.static._Future__propagateToListeners<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:22727:17
._Future._completeWithValue$1<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:22542:7
._Future__asyncComplete_closure0.call$0<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:22823:7
._rootRun<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:21803:7
._ZoneDelegate.run$2<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:24837:7
.VmTurnZone__onScheduleMicrotask_closure.call$0<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:13356:7
.VmTurnZone._finishTurn$2<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:13286:13
.VmTurnZone._onRunBase$4<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:13253:11
.VmTurnZone._onRunUnary$5<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:13261:7
anonymous/<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js line 3346 > Function:1:28
._ZoneDelegate.runUnary$3<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:24846:7
._CustomizedZone.runUnary$2<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:25061:7
._BaseZone.runUnaryGuarded$2<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:24947:9
._BaseZone_bindUnaryCallback_closure.call$1<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:25018:7
.invokeClosure_closure0.call$0<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:4701:7
._IsolateContext.eval$1<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:1793:9
._callInIsolate<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:1269:1
.invokeClosure<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:3171:7
.convertDartClosureToJS</$function</<@http://localhost:8080/main.dart.js:3191:9
"
```

Of course if I remove the "myCallback" binding, everything works. I'm using Angular 0.12, Dart 1.5.1.

Comment: 'The code works in the VM but not in the regular browser.' What does this mean? Did you run it with pub serve, pub build? Which Angular.dart version are you using. How does your myController class look like? Did you specify the Angular transformer in pubspec.yaml?

Comment: - It works in Chromium but not in Chrome or Firefox. - pub serve. - Angular 0.12. - Yes, I'm specifying the transformer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent some function from being "Tree shaked away"  you can:
Assign this function to some variable in the code and, for example, call `.toString()` or you can mark it as used in mirrors with the [MirrorsUsed](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart%3amirrors.MirrorsUsed) and it won't bloat code too much. But the minification can also be a problem.